# Is it possible to share a file with Intent.ACTION_SEND from a URL (and not from a local URI)?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-sharing

I'm trying to share a file like so:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(mAttachments.get(mCurrentPosition).url));
shareIntent.setType(mAttachments.get(mCurrentPosition).type);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share_with)));
```

where `mAttachments.get(mCurrentPosition).url` is a URL pointing to a file, like `https://dl.mywebsite.com/a_photo.jpg` or `https://dl.mywebsite.com/a_file.pdf`, and `mAttachments.get(mCurrentPosition).type` is the mimetype. I'm trying it out with Gmail but getting the following exception:

```
W/Gmail   (21099): Error opening file to obtain size.
W/Gmail   (21099): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://dl.mywebsite.com/a_photo.jpg
W/Gmail   (21099):  at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1066)
W/Gmail   (21099):  at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:921)
W/Gmail   (21099):  at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:778)
W/Gmail   (21099):  at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:733)
...etc.
```

The docs (http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) seem to indicate that you should download the file to local storage first, then use a `FileProvider` or something to set permissions on the resultant URI. Is it possible to do this without downloading the file first?